# Does Eindhoven Airport offer flight transfer?

Tags: self-transfer, eindhoven

I'm arriving on a different airline than I'm leaving, do I need to pass through security again or can I transfer flights airside at this airport?

Comment: No mention of "connection" or "transfer" on their website, and neither the map on their website nor Google Maps (including Street View inside most of the terminal) seem to show anything that would allow you get from one aircraft to another without going landside and then back through security (with possible passport control both on the arrivals and departure sides if the flights are from/to non-Schengen airports). But I'm not familiar with the airport, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @jcaron I checked their website before asking here for local knowledge or personal experience, not sure if Google Street View would have airside views though.

Comment: It does have views of most of the airside. The only relevant parts not covered are arrivals passport control, security, and the area after departure passport control. But in airside arrivals you see there's only one way you can go, and that is to the exit. Note that given that the airport seems to cater mostly to low-cost airlines, it's not surprising there are no airside transit facilities.

Comment: That's very interesting stuff, I've never seen anything like that before. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you arrive at Eindhoven airport you disembark the airplane, get a short walk under a roofed walkway and go immediately to the baggage claim area and from there you reach the main hall, along the red path in the picture.

[image]

If there is any passport control because you are coming from outside EU, it is done on the same path. There is no direct physical connection for passengers between this route and the gates. You need to go again through security checks from the entrance.

If you have checked in baggage, you will also need to pick it up and check it back in.

Comment: Luckily I have only a single hand luggage.

Answer (score 8):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers transiting through Amsterdam (AMS)...

So no, Eindhoven does **not** offer flight transfer and you need to pass through security again

Comment: Could you please report the whole sentence? It is hard to tell what it means from just that brief snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a self transfer, you most likely won't have a choice, but to go to the landside on arrival. Eindhoven Airport is fairly small and I don't think they have options for a connection (I'm not 100% sure).
A while back I had a layover there, all passengers on board needed to leave the plane for refuel. They pack everybody who didn't have Eindhoven as the final destination in a warehouse looking room for about 40 minutes before we boarded again. However, I understand that this was possible only because everybody was traveling on the same plane with the same airline.